# Updating a sub document queried with $or condition in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have an order document that looks like this

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f70ba6dfb59c87f6b07a1ad"), 
    "state" : "CART", "storeId" : "1", "userId" : "johndoe", 
    "orderItems" : [
        {
            "productId" : "169",
            "offerId" : "112233",
            "sku" : "product-sku-1",
            "name" : "Product Awesome A",
            "quantity" : 1,
            "retailPrice" : 495,
            "salePrice" : 395
        },
        {
            "productId" : "170",
            "offerId" : "112234",
            "sku" : "product-sku-2",
            "name" : "Product Awesome B",
            "quantity" : 1,
            "retailPrice" : 595,
            "salePrice" : 495
        }
    ]
}
```

Problem: I want to find an orderItem that has either productId or sku with value product-sku-1 and set the quantity to 2.

So, I tried the following

```
db.order.update(
    { 
      "userId":"johndoe", "state":"CART",
      $or: [ 
             {"orderItems.productId":"product-sku-1"}, 
             {"orderItems.sku":"product-sku-1"}
      ]
    },
    { 
      $set : {"orderItems.$.quantity":2}
    }
)
```

This gives me an error

```
"can't append to array using string field name [$]"
```

If I remove the or condition and query on just one field of sub document like below, everything works fine as expected with the quantity set to 2.

```
db.order.update(
    { 
      "userId":"johndoe", "state":"CART",
      "orderItems.sku":"product-sku-1"
    },
    { 
      $set : {"orderItems.$.quantity":2}
    }
)
```

My application receives either sku or productId as the identifier field. I do not know if it is a sku or productId at the time of query. So, I need to be able to query on either of the fields in sub document and update the quantity.

Note that I need the update done atomically. I really do not want to do two updates one after another.

Am I missing something here? Is there another elegant way of doing it?

Comment: I found the answer after carefully reading the difference between dot-notation and sub-objects http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer after carefully reading the difference between dot-notation and [sub-objects in this post](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29). I came to the following solution:

```
db.order.update(
    { 
      "userId":"johndoe", "state":"CART",
      "orderItems" : { 
          $elemMatch : { $or:[{"productId":"product-sku-1"}, {"sku":"product-sku-1"}] }
      }
    },
    { 
      $set : {"orderItems.$.quantity":2}
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This use of $ is not supported. The $or query does not set the value of the $ positional operator, so MongoDB thinks you're looking for a field named "$", which is prohibited.

I suggest that you simply issue two updates, one filtering by productId, the other filtering by sku. Only one of the updates will actually change a document.

Comment: I am currently using the multiple updates approach. I wanted to see if there's a way to do it in one update. Thanks for taking time to explain the error thrown.